# Removing decorators while creating the element

Tags: zend-framework

am having a problem removing error decorators from my form..this is how i create my elements:

```
$this->setAttribute('method','post');
$this->add(
    array(
        'name'=>'username',
        'attributes'=>array(
            'type'=>'text',
            'id'=>'username',
        ),
        'options'=>array(
            'label'=>'Username'
        ),
    )
);
```

is there  a way i can remove decorators from here or  can it be done from the controller..i have researched on it but cant find a  good answer..thanks in advance..

Comment: Does this syntax work for element adding to form?

Comment: yeah..it works..its just a section from the constructor..

Answer (score 1):

It's basically impossible. If you really want to avoid one of the decorators while creating the element, you have to pass list of all desired decorators but one, for example:

```
// Zend_Form based class body
$this->addElement('text', 'myfield', array(
        'label' => 'My field',
        'decorators' => array(
                'ViewHelper',
                array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'div')),
        ),
);
```

However, simpler way is just removing single decorator by name, just after creating the element. If you're in Zend_Form based class, just invoke:

```
$this->getElement('myfield')->removeDecorator('Errors');
```

The removeDecorator() method is public, so you can use it in the controller:

```
$form = new My_Form();
$form->getElement('myfield')->removeDecorator('Errors');
```